# What's the opposite of var-export function in php?

Tags: php, variable-assignment

I export a variable to a textarea via "[var_export](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php)($schools,true)" so user can edit it. Then  I want to 'update' the variable with the changes made. The updates is received via POST method.

I have some **text** that I want to **become a variable**. How can I do that?

What I do right now is that I edit the variable manually in .php file. I want to give an web interface to users do to the same. There won't be no security issues as this will be strictly inhouse tool only.

Sample of the variable

```
$schools = array(

    "PHCS"=> array(
        "full_name"=> "Pacific Hills Christian School",
        "version"=> "4.0.2b",
        "etc"=> "etc"
      ),

    "WAC"=> array(
        "full_name"=> "Wollondilly Anglican College",
        "version"=> "4.0.1",
        "etc"=> "etc"
      ),
  );
```

Comment: I'm afraid to say `eval`. Can't you use a simpler format like JSON, which has a dedicated parse method?

Comment: More information would be helpful. How will you retrieve the data from that textfield? via post, via jquery or javascript with an event listener etc.

Comment: There's a pretty interesting function called `print_r_reverse()` that was submitted by a user a few years ago. Have a look at it: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php#93529

Comment: @busypeoples: I get the data via POST.

Comment: Avoid eval. What will you do if the user breaks that multi array? Where is it being saved to? There is a better and simpler approach. Do PHCS and every other array in $schools have the same structure. Then you could easily solve the problem by writing a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be looking at using [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) which use of is pretty controversial due to security risks.

I would suggest you use [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php), or even better, the [JSON](http://au.php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php) functions instead.

The JSON encode/decode would be the best option for displaying to the user as it's fairly readable.

Answer (score 0):

Following the advice on php.net, if you plan to change the object you should use serialize and unserialize:

```
$var = serialize(array('hello'));
// string(22) "a:1:{i:0;s:5:"hello";}"
var_dump( unserialize($var) );
```

Comment: Serialization wouldn't be suitable for the use in the question, users would have to count the amount of characters in their strings for it to work properly.